# DataTable. The "select" method returns only one row

Tags: c#, datatable, datagrid

dataGridView1 has a `select` field of type `bool`.
Programmatically select two lines.

Using the "Select" method, I select rows with the field "select" = true.

The code displays in `DataRow [] selectedRows;` only the last line. (the line `dataGridView1 [" select ", 1] is displayed. Value = true;`)

The string `dataGridView1 [" select ", 0] .Value = true;` in `DataRow [] selectedRows;` is missing.

How to make that in `DataRow [] selectedRows;` there were all rows with the field "select" = true.?

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dtTest;

dataGridView1["select", 0].Value = true;
dataGridView1["select", 1].Value = true;

DataRow[] selectedRows;
selectedRows = dtTest.Select("select = true");
```

**Update.**
Database - MSAccess
The field "id" is the primary key.

[image]

Comment: Did you select : dataGridView1.MultiSelect = true;

Comment: @jdweng I do not understand.
What are you offering?
could you describe your offer in more detail?

Comment: A DGV defaults to only allowing one row to be selected.  To allow multi-select you must change the defaults property.

Comment: @ jdweng Made. Does not help.
I do not understand how this relates to my problem.
I programmatically change the value of the cells in the "DGV", the changes fall into `DataTable dtTest`.
I checked in `DataTable dtTest` two strings have `"select" = true`.
I am sampling from `DataTable dtTest`, and I only get the result of the last line with `"select" = true`.

Comment: Does you database have a primary key?  When the database has a primary key you can only have one row with the same key and that could be the reason you only get the last entry.  If you want more than one item with the same value you cannot have a primary key.

Comment: @jdweng Updated the question.
There is a primary key. If I understand correctly, the primary key is different for all records.
And so in this situation, problems with the keys can not be.
Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: The last row with the asterisk is to allow the user to add new rows.  If you are only getting the last row with the asterisk then the query isn't returning anything.You have spaces in the column name (dataGridView1 [" select ", 0] ).  Why?  If the datasource is a datatable then use : var selectedRows = dtTest.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("select") == "true").ToList();

Comment: @jdweng ** 1. ** `The last row with the asterisk is to allow the user to add new rows`. I get the row` Row_2`. And the string `Row_1` I do not get. I do not understand how the string with an asterisk affects my problem.
Note: after I set the "select" = true field for the `Row_1` and` Row_2` lines in `dataGridView1`, the values ​​for these lines also changed in` DataTable dtTest`.

Comment: @jdweng ** 2. ** I get an error in your expression
`" Failed to cast the \ "System.Boolean \" object type to \ "System.String \". "Failed to cast the \" System.Boolean \ "object type to \" System.String \ ".`
I need to get a collection of rows with all the fields. Will your expression allow this?

** 3. ** It is strange that I ran into such a problem. In other situations, the `Select` method worked fine.
True, I did not use it for fields like `bool`

Comment: Then true is stored as a boolean in the data base : dtTest.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<boolean>("select") == true).ToList();

Comment: @jdweng 1. It works.
2. The solution you propose goes through all the lines and selects the necessary ones.
Method "Select" also works on this principle?